# Extract a function name inside a macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In C, we often have to run such code

```
if (! somefun(x, y, z)) {
    perror("somefun")
}
```

Is it possible to create a macro which, used as follows:

```
#define chkerr ...
chkerr(somefun(x, y, z));
```

would compile to the above?

I already know I can use `__VA_ARGS__` macro, but this would require me to call it like

```
chkerr(somefun, x, y, z)
```

Comment: If `sumfun` is something that can change (name of various func) you cannot achieve the result without passing the name of function to the macro, as you did with __VA_ARGS__

Comment: If you want to extract the name, you'll have to pass it as a parameter, so the `chkerr(somefun, x, y, z)` syntax will be necessary to achieve your goal.  You can do that with `__VA_ARGS__` of course: `#define chkerr(fun, ...) do { if (fun(__VA_ARGS__)) perror(#fun); } while (0)`.

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me](http://ideone.com/yuwYbY).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes but he want's the name of the function in the name of the message.

Comment: @AndreKampling Updated example, using the stringification preprocessor operator. It *does* show the full call with arguments, not only the function name though.

Answer (score 21):

Short variant (you spotted already):

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION, ...)  \
    if(!FUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    {                          \
        perror(#FUNCTION);     \
    }
```

Be aware that this can impose big problems in nested if/else or similar constructs:

```
if(x)
    chkErr(f, 10, 12) //;
                      //^ semicolon forgotten!
else
    chkErr(f, 12, 10);
```

would compile to code equivalent to the following:

```
if(x)
{
    if(!f(10, 12))
        perror("f");
    else if(!f, 12, 10))
        perror("f");
}
```

Quite obviously not what was intended with the if/else written with the macros... So you really should prefer to let it look like a real function (*requiring* a semicolon):

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION, ...)      \
    do                             \
    {                              \
        if(!FUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)) \
        {                          \
            perror(#FUNCTION);     \
        }                          \
    }                              \
    while(0)
```

You would call it like this:

```
chkErr(someFunction, 10, 12);
```

In case of error, output would be:

```
someFunction: <error text>
```

**However**, this hides the fact that a function actually gets called, making it more difficult to understand for "outsiders". Same output, not hiding the function call, but requiring one additional comma in between function and arguments (compared to a normal function call):

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION, ARGUMENTS) \
do                                  \
{                                   \
    if(!FUNCTION ARGUMENTS)         \
    {                               \
        perror(#FUNCTION);          \
    }                               \
}                                   \
while(0)

chkErr(someFunction,(12, 10));
//                 ^ (!)
```

Another variant with the charm of retaining the function call would print out this entire function call:

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION_CALL)   \
do                              \
{                               \
    if(!FUNCTION_CALL)          \
    {                           \
        perror(#FUNCTION_CALL); \
    }                           \
}                               \
while(0)

chkErr(someFunction(10, 12));
```

In case of error, output would be:

```
someFunction(10, 12): <error text>
```

**Addendum:** If you really want *exactly* the output as shown in the question *and* still have the function call retained (without comma in between), you are a little in trouble. Actually, it *is* possible, but it requires some extra work:

Problem is how the preprocessor operates on macro arguments: Each argument is a token. It can easily combine tokens, but cannot split them.

Leaving out any commas results in the macro accepting one single token, just as in my second variant. Sure, you can stringify it, as I did, but you get the function arguments with. This is a string literal, and as the pre-processor cannot modify string literals, you have to operate on them at *runtime*.

Next problem then is, though, string literals are unmodifiable. So you need to modify a *copy*!

The following variant would do all this work for you:

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION_CALL)                                 \
do                                                            \
{                                                             \
    if(!FUNCTION_CALL)                                        \
    {                                                         \
        char function_name[] = #FUNCTION_CALL;                \
        char* function_name_end = strchr(function_name, '('); \
        if(function_name_end)                                 \
            *function_name_end = 0;                           \
        perror(function_name);                                \
    }                                                         \
}                                                             \
while(0)
```

Well, decide you if it is worth the effort...

By the way - whitespace between function name and opening parenthesis is not eliminated. If you want to be *perfect*:

```
unsigned char* end = (unsigned char*) function_name;
while(*end && *end != '(' && !isspace(*end))
    ++end;
*end = 0;
```

Or, much nicer (thanks chqrlie for the hint):

```
function_name[strcspn(function_name, "( \t")] = 0;
```

Anything else I can think of would require an additional pre-processing step:

```
#define CAT(X, Y) CAT_(X, Y)
#define CAT_(X, Y) X ## Y

#define chkErr(FUNCTION_CALL)                 \
do                                            \
{                                             \
    if(!FUNCTION_CALL)                        \
    {                                         \
        perror(CAT(CHK_ERR_TEXT_, __LINE__)); \
    }                                         \
}                                             \
while 0

chkErr(function(10, 12));
```

Ah, huh, this would result in code like this:

```
if(!function(10, 12))
{
    perror(CHK_ERR_TEXT_42);
}
```

And now, where to get these macros from? Well, the pre-processing, remember? Possibly a perl or python script, e. g. generating an additional header file you'd have to include. You would have to make sure this pre-processing is done every time before the compiler's pre-processor runs.

Well, all not impossible to solve, but I'll leave this to the masochists among us...

Comment: Playing Mr Picky: perfection would require `isspace((unsigned char)*end)`. You could also use a one-liner: `function_name[strcspn(function_name, "( \t")] = '\0';`.  The double `!!` is also inconsistent with the example.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the double exclamation mark - copy past error, used it to test as I used printf as function. Unsigned char? Hm, must admit, as since C99 function names aren't limited to basic source character set any more... Old hare learning new stuff: wasn't aware of strcspn -- thanks again...

Comment: Note that the first version of the macro screws up `if (xyz()) chkErr(pqr, a, b c); else def();` because `def()` is now associated with the `pqr()` and not the `xyz()`.  You either need to add a dangling `else` to the macro or use the second form.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Truth spoken, extended answer appropriately. One really shouldn't drop principles for brevity here...

Comment: Ever the pest (that's me I'm referring to): `#define chkErr(function, ...) (function(__VA_ARGS__) || perror(#function))`?  Or variants on this theme.  I'm not convinced a ternary operator helps here, but it might.  Also, there could be issues if the function being checked takes no parameters — the variants using `FUNCTION_CALL` avoid that problem.  GCC has special syntax for it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Haha, the `||` variant looks very perl-like... Shouldn't work, though, as perror returns void... Empty __VA_ARGS__ should not be a problem as there is no comma involved, as in this variant: `#define PRINTF(FORMAT, __VA_ARGS__) printf(FORMAT, ## __VA_ARGS__)`. Yeah, using GCC extension...

Comment: You can work around perror's voidness with `(perror(#function),0)`.  C doesn't have so many operators for no reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, should have thought of myself... I like this kind of abbreviations, wondering, though, how many would agree with us in superior readability...

Comment: Oh; it isn't superior readability — it's just covering obscure bases.  Well, there are those who are confused by the `do { … } while (0)` notation in macros.  Also, you can use `(a || b)` in contexts that cannot support `do { … } while (0)` or `if (!a) b`.  Whether that's a good thing is another matter.  There are advantages to limiting the macro to use where a statement can be used.

Comment: `if(chkErr(f(10, 12)))` -- possible with `||`, not with `do{}while(0)`. Suppose, in the *specific* case, we should prefer the latter...

Comment: You could have the syntax be `chkErr(somefun,(x, y, z))`

Comment: @Justin Exactly!  There's no need to just leap to variadics here; furthermore, `#define checkErr(F,A)` doesn't need fancy work or extensions to handle things like empty argument lists; that's just `checkErr(nullary,())`.

Comment: Hm, thought of that, too, but as there is still a comma left, didn't consider it superior to the `__VAR_ARGS__` solution. Seems as if I've been wrong??? Well, added it now.

Answer (score 8):

> **C11 6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers**
>
> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

You can used it this way:

```
#define chkErr(exp)  do { if (!(exp)) perror(__func__); } while (0)

chkerr(somefun(x, y, z));
```

Unfortunately, this would produce an error message with the name of the calling function, not `somefun`.  Here is a simple variant that should work and even produce more informative error messages:

```
#define chkErr(exp)  do { if (!(exp)) perror(#exp); } while (0)

chkerr(somefun(x, y, z));
```

In case `somefun(x, y, z)` returns a non zero value, the error message will contain the string `"somefun(x, y, z)"`.

You can combine both techniques to give both the offending call and the location:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define chkErr(exp)  \
    do { if (!(exp)) \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: in function %s, %s failed: %s\n",\
                __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #exp, strerror(errno)); \
    } while (0)

chkerr(somefun(x, y, z));
```

This assumes `somefun()` returns `0` or `NULL` in case of error and set `errno` accordingly. Note however that most system calls return non zero in case of error.

Comment: This would not work. If he call that in the `main` function then `__func__` will be `main` and not `somefun`.

Comment: @AndreKampling: answer completed with alternative solutions

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with an ugly, unsafe variadic macro:

```
#define chkerr(func, ...) \
if(!func(__VA_ARGS__))    \
{                         \
  perror(#func);          \
}

...
chkerr(somefunc, 1, 2, 3);
```

But it is a very bad idea.

---

Call for sanity:

If there was just the original code with the plain `if` statement, the reader would think "Here they call a function and do some basic error control. Okay, basic stuff. Moving on...". But after the changes, anyone who reads the code will instead freeze and think "WTF is this???".

You can never write a macro that is clearer than the if statement - which makes the if statement superior to the macro.

Some rules to follow:

- Function-like macros are dangerous and unreadable. They should only be used as the very last resort.
- Avoid inventing your own secret macro language with function-like macros. C programmers who read your code know C. They don't know your secret macro language.
- "To avoid typing" is often a poor rationale for program design decisions. Avoiding code repetition is a good rationale, but taking it to the extremes will affect code readability. If you avoid code repetition and make the code more readable at the same time, it is a good thing. If you do it but the code turns less readable, it is hard to justify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the original call format:

```
chkerr(somefun(x, y, z));
```

With a macro and a helper function:

```
#define chkerr(fcall) \
    if (!fcall) { \
        perror(extract_fname(#fcall)); \
    }
const char *extract_fname(const char *fcall);
```

The `extract_fname` function would get text and return everything until the open parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to extract *just* the function name. The C processor sees the literals you pass as single tokens, [which can't be manipulated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600924/1350184) Your only options are to print the function with arguments like Aconcague suggests or pass the name as a separate parameter:

```
#define chkErr(FUNCTION_NAME, FUNCTION_CALL) \
if(!FUNCTION_CALL) \
{ \
    perror(#FUNCTION_NAME); \
}

chkErr(someFunction, someFunction(10, 12));
```